# Error executing action `create` on resource 'cookbook_file

Tags: chef-recipe

Getting an error while executing action 'create' on a resource. I am running the recipe in --local-mode not sure if that is the problem.

I am just trying to run it locally first instead of running it on a node.

Pasting my file and my output in here :

```
[2019-04-09T19:25:51+00:00] WARN: Node rheaj has an empty run list.
Converging 4 resources
Recipe: @recipe_files::/home/rheaj/chef/cookbooks/oc_jumpbox/recipes/default.rb
  * cookbook_file[/etc/motd] action create[2019-04-09T19:25:51+00:00] INFO: Processing cookbook_file[/etc/motd] action create (@recipe_files::/home/rheaj/chef/cookbooks/oc_jumpbox/recipes/default.rb line 9)


    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'cookbook_file[/etc/motd]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound
    ----------------------------------
    Cookbook @recipe_files not found. If you're loading @recipe_files from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /home/rheaj/chef/cookbooks/oc_jumpbox/recipes/default.rb


      9: cookbook_file '/etc/motd' do
     10:   group 'root'
     11:   user 'root'
     12:   mode '0644'
     13:   source 'motd'
     14: end
     15:
```

Answer (score 0):

Default location for your `cookbook_files` is in `files/default`. The error you get is that your cookbook file is not there. Can you create that file `files/default/motd` and re run your chef-client.